# Android broadcast loosing Bundle data

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bundle

I have Service and Activity in my application.
In the Service I do this:

```
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString("message_id", "123");
            data.putString("user_id", "321");

            Intent dataIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION).putExtra("message_read", data);
            sendBroadcast(dataIntent);
```

In the Activity I get broadcast and try to parse it:

```
            if (intent.hasExtra("message_read")) {
                Bundle messageReadData = intent.getBundleExtra("message_read");
                updateItem(messageReadData.getString("message_id"), messageReadData);
            }
```

But messageReadData here has not any data. So messageReadData.getString("message_id") will be Null. Why does it happen?

Comment: I think you need to use setInetnt(intent) in the method onNewIntent()

Comment: try to make your bundle `static`

Comment: Never make any bundle static. Their purpose was to facilitate inter-component data transfer without depending on static variables.

Comment: I'd recommend a couple of things: 1) provide more code, this doesn't show how the `Activity` got the `Intent`. It can be inferred that this is really a programmatically registered `BroadcastReceiver` which is hosted by the `Activity`, but it is not clear. 2) Don't use literal strings for your keys (e.g. `"message_id"`). All it takes is a typo in your call to `.getString()` in the `BroadcastReceiver` compared to what the `Service` used in `.putString()` and you have a problem.  Create and use constants (`static final String` in Java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, that debugger doesn't see content of Bundle until I get some value from Bundle. So, I was incorrect by saying that messageReadData.getString("message_id") will be Null. It's not right. Seems Bundle or Intent supports lazy parsing.